# How does filters interact with authentication providers in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

If I understand correctly, the AuthenticationProvider authenticate Authentication that they support, but how does the Authentication object gets created in the first place?

Is it the filter's responsibility to initialize them?

At what point are they passed into the providers?

Answer (score 0):

See [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html):

> In most cases, the framework transparently takes care of managing the security context and authentication objects for you.

Authentication is a Spring managed bean. It´s initializated by the Spring framework and passed to the Authentication provider by default when the context is created.